# where can I find 'pkunzip.cpp and pkunzip.h"?

Tags: c++

somewhere, I found a simple source to read something, and that source includes
"PkunZip.cpp" and "Pkunzip.h" to read zip-file.

However, I could not find the website about PkunZip.cpp ( sourceforge or codeproject etc ).

where can I find the website that describe 'pkunzip.cpp' and a manual about it?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the PK code is not free, so you probably won't find it on sourceforge. Like Jan Hudec said, zlib is an open alternative. And I think the 7zip code is open, too, and supports the standard zip format as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you search google for either of these files nothing is returned. That is a pretty bad sign. If you need code to handle zip archives, I have used [libarchive](http://code.google.com/p/libarchive/) in the past with great success. Their website has great documentation and the code is cross platform (Windows, *BSD, Linux, etc).

You should be able to replace any missing functionality with libarchive.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of reading zip files is [zlib](http://zlib.net/), or considering you tagged `c++`, the [zipios](http://zipios.sourceforge.net/). But if you want your particular files, have you tried [Google Codesearch](http://codesearch.google.com/)?